# powers of primitive element are linearly independent

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb{F}_{q^m}$ be an extension field of the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$. Let $T := Tr_{\mathbb{F_{q^m}}|\mathbb{F}_q}$ be the trace map and $\gamma$ a primitive element of $\mathbb{F}_{q^m}$.

Prove that for ever integer $k$ the elements $\gamma^k$, $\gamma^{k+1}$, ... ,$\gamma^{k+m-1}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{F}_q$. Moreover, show that there exists an integer $0 \leq k \leq q^{m-2}$ such that $T(\gamma^k) = T(\gamma^{k+1}) = ... = T(\gamma^{k+m-1}) = 0$.

I am already stuck with the first part. I have to show that if

$c_0\gamma + c_1\gamma^{k+1}+ ... +c_{m-1}\gamma^{k+m-1} = 0 $ for $c_i \in \mathbb{F}_q$ then all $c_i = 0$

but I don't know how to do this.

Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show that $c_0\gamma^k+c_1\gamma^{k+1}+\cdots+c_{m-1}\gamma^{k+m-1}=0$ if and only if $c_0+c_1\gamma+\cdots+c_{m-1}\gamma^{m-1}=0$?

Comment: I cannot do the second claim because it is false. Either it should be asking you to prove that this is impossible, ot the claim should involve one trace less.